# What did he become after the New Year?

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

**Try your best to solve the puzzle below GOOD LUCK!**

Famous Disney character missing a dog and er… a kitchen utensil? (3)

Half an Apple, empty, without hydrogen makes the sun shine! (6)

He likes to zap badly hurt zebras and America? (4)

A single Greek city collided with the top of another symbolizes wisdom? (6)

Sheer Minister gone bananas makes quite a messenger! (6)

The gauge being noisy is someone helpful for harvest! (7)

Sea lurker is posterior somewhat behind the Don with a number and I central! (8)

SOS after dead English Princess was found next to 3/4s a gem! A heavy drinker sadly! (8)

He, a famous Egyptian deity invents lady for a good marriage! (4)

```
PLACE CONTENTS IN A 3 BY 3 

AND DIAL UP FOR HELP!!

       (1,1) (7,3) (7,4) 
       (4,5) (9,5) (6,1)
       (5,2) (2,5) (3,4)

             (8,2)
```

**Edit: Tried to make the way forward less tricky.**

Hint:

> The cryptic clues all share a common theme!

Comment: I edited the puzzle again to make the second half easier

Answer (score 5):

[Partial answer. I can't see what's going on with the grid of number pairs.]

I'm not 100% sure about everything, but I think I have all nine answers.

Famous Disney character missing a dog and er... a kitchen utensil? (3)

> **PAN** (kitchen utensil) = (PETER) **PAN** missing PET and ER.

Half an Apple, empty, without hydrogen makes the sun shine! (6)

> **APOLLO** (makes the sun shine) = **AP**(PLE) + (H)**OLLO**, says Stiv

He likes to zap badly hurt zebras and America? (4)

> **ZEUS** (he likes to zap) = **ZE**bras (?) + **US**

A single Greek city collided with the top of another symbolizes wisdom? (6)

> **ATHENA** (symbolizes wisdom) = **ATHEN** ("singular" of Athens) + **A**nother

Sheer Minister gone bananas makes quite a messenger! (6)

> **HERMES** (a messenger) = (**SHEER** + **M**inister)*

The gauge being noisy is someone helpful for harvest! (7)

> **DEMETER** (someone helpful for harvest) sounds like "the meter"

Sea lurker is posterior somewhat behind the Don with a number and I central! (8)

> **POSEIDON** (sea lurker) = **POS**(T) + **E** (base of natural logarithm) + **I** + **DON**

SOS after dead English Princess was found next to 3/4s a gem! A heavy drinker sadly! (8)

> **DIONYSOS** (heavy drinker) = **DI** + **ONY**(X) + **SOS**

He, a famous Egyptian deity invents lady for a good marriage! (4)

> **HERA** (lady for a good marriage) = **HE** + **RA**

What now?

> The number pairs (*m*, *n*) suggest that we have to take letter *n* from answer *m*. There are nine answers and ten pairs and every number from 1 to 9 occurs at least once. (7 occurs twice.)
>
>  Unfortunately, this means we have to the the fifth letter from the four-letter answer **HERA**. (But the top row yields the promising **PSE**, which could be the start to something along the lines of "[PSE solver (No.) I](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users)") Perhaps the answers must be sorted, but then we have to take the fifth letter from **ZEUS**.
>
>  The answers are all Greek deities and all except Pan are one of the [Twelve Olympians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Olympians). Most of have a Roman counterpart:
>
>  Pan      — **FAUNUS**
>  Apollo   — ?
>  Zeus     — **JUPITER**
>  Athena   — **MINERVA**
>  Hermes   — **MERCURY**
>  Demeter  — **CERES**
>  Poseidon — **NEPTUNE**
>  Dionysos — **BACCHUS**
>  Hera     — **JUNO**
>
>  But these have the same problem: We need the fifth leter from **JUNO**. There's also a connection to the solar system with Mercury, Jupiter, Neptune and the asteroid / dwarf planet Ceres, but the other goddesses and gods don't fit.

Comment: This is the same place I got stuck. Although I had one difference - I had #2 as rot13(NCBYYB sebz NC(-cyr) + (-u)BYYB)

Comment: Stiv is correct

Comment: @Stiv: Your answer fits better and it accounts for "empty". And it doesn't try to shoehorn a Golden Delicious in in a ludicrous manner. (When I saw the first answer, No. 9, I just worked backwards from the definitions.)

Comment: You are a little on the right track on the second half but you went off the rails

Comment: Check the edits it should be clearer how to proceed

Comment: Apollo's roman name is Phoebus or Apollo

Comment: @RonchenLuo: Perhaps, but the correspondence of Greek to Roman deities doesn't seem to be the right angle to attack this. (In my opinion, Pan doesn't really fit in.) I still think we need to do something with the words themselves, but the additional "3×3" has me still stumped.